# Declaring Arrays Dynamically in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to create `arrays` of specific length dynamically, so that I can use them in a bigger procedure.

**Sample Data:**

[image]

The below code using the `Dictionary` Gives me the Count and Unique File Extensions in the Data.

**Code:**

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each cel In Range("B1:B8")
    I = 1
    If Not dict.Exists(cel.Text) Then
        dict.Add cel.Text, I

    Else
        temp = dict(cel.Text) + 1
        dict.Remove cel.Text
        dict.Add cel.Text, temp
    End If
Next cel

For Each varKey In dict.Keys

Debug.Print varKey & ":" & dict.Item(varKey)

Next
```

**Result:**

[image]

What I am trying to do is create 3 (in this sample) arrays `pdf(4)`,`xlsx(3)`,`docm(1)`
Using the results from Dictionary.

But the line `Dim varkey(dict.Item(varKey)) As Variant` gives me *Compile Error*.

> Constant Expression Required

Is there a way to do it ? I searched google for ways to achieve this, but with no luck.

Basically what I want is to use these different extension names to declare Arrays. But these extension names will vary so I need to declare them dynamically. Array should have same name as the Extension.

So pick the name from sheet or from Dictionary and declare that as Array of a specified Length. Length can be Redim'ed afterwards also, but the main problem is declaring them from a variable.

Comment: Why not use `ReDim`?

Comment: It says Invalid `ReDim` if I try Redim. I want all the Arrays to have the Name of the Extension. How many names are there & number of files is determined using the Dictionary above

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. I thought you had pre-determined names for each array. What is that actual task at hand?

Comment: Basically what I want is to use these different extension names to declare Arrays. But these extension names will vary so I need to declare them dynamically. Array should have same name as the Extension.

Comment: How can an array change its name?

Comment: So 1st part of the Code is collecting all the files from a chosen folder by User. And different folders can have different files.

Comment: Said a different way - how can an array, i.e. a variable, change its name?

Comment: I think I am getting you question wrong @BigBen ... There is no variable initially. I want to declare them using results from Dictionary or reading the Name from Sheet. So in a statement `Dim arr() As Variant` I want to use a variable in place of `arr`

Comment: You can't dynamically declare a variable. `Dim` statements are not executable. That's why this sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: Is this what you are trying? **1.** `Dim varkey As Variant` **2.** `Dim n as Long: n=Val(dict.Item(varKey))` **3.** `Redim varkey(n)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. That's sort of what I am trying to Do. but here varkey is also a Variable. Maybe this is not possible, given the answer by BigBen

Comment: Dictionary of Collections might be what you are looking for. Dictionary of arrays is also possible, but it is not efficient to modify those arrays after adding to dictionary.

Comment: What you are looking for is called `Variable Variable`. If you search google using this term then you will find lot of links. Now I have one question. Let's you have declared arrays dynamically as you want it. Then what next? Will those array interact with each other or will you be processing the array one by one?

Comment: I want to call them Individually, like by calling all the pdf files by pdf(1) or `pdf(ubound(pdf))` or similarly with the other formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BrakNicku commented a Dictionary of Dictionaries will get you the answer that you want.

```
Sub PrintExtensionCount()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Map As New Scripting.Dictionary, subMap As New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each Cell In Range("B1:B8")
        If Not Map.Exists(Cell.Value) Then Map.Add Cell.Text, New Dictionary

        Set subMap = Map(Cell.Value)
        subMap.Add Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, vbNullString
    Next

    Dim Key As Variant

    For Each Key In Map
        Set subMap = Map(Key)
        Debug.Print Key; ":"; subMap.Count
    Next

End Sub
```

### Result

[image: Immediate Window Result]

Not to confuse things but I like to use a Dictionary of ArrayList.

```
Sub PrintExtensionCount()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Map As New Scripting.Dictionary, list As Object

    For Each Cell In Range("B1:B8")
        If Not Map.Exists(Cell.Value) Then Map.Add Cell.Text, CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

        Set list = Map(Cell.Value)
        list.Add Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next

    Dim Key As Variant

    For Each Key In Map
        Set list = Map(Key)
        Debug.Print Key; ":"; list.Count
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a Way I can call `Debug.Print Map(pdf).Count` ? will it work ? If i just want to use the pdf .. I want to be able to call that directly without looping through the keys.. Like `pdf(1)` for  1st pdf file or `pdf(ubound(pdf))` for last pdf file

Comment: Cool .. They are working as an Array only that I have to add use `Map("pdf")` instead of `pdf` 

Comment: You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and read [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the task at hand is, but this is an X-Y problem, if I understand your comments.

`Dim` statements - [declarative statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/writing-declaration-statements) - are not executable. This is regardless of the type (`String`, `Long`, `Variant` array, whatever.) Your question title might have been bit misleading in that regard, since it seems like essentially you're trying to dynamically declare *variables* - the fact they are *arrays* is coincidental.

You can avoid the compile error by `ReDim`ming an array based on the count from your dictionary, but you can't come up with a dynamic list of variables.